# Change in nature of Job and work domain

Tags: recruitment, work-experience

I have an experience of 6 years in IT sector like Oracle, Honeywell and Deloitte (Quote to Order team & Project management operations team), but I always wanted to start my own manufacturing company and head that, now with the help of one of my close family member I am working to start a new manufacturing company under the flagship of his existing company.

But we are facing a several challenges in selling our new machines (Eg : Delay in getting some imported items, fabrication work from 3rd party vendors etc).

Because of these, we are still in zero revenue and expenses are running high.
If the trend continues we may have to shut down the project.

Will I be able to go back once again to regular job which I was doing earlier ? Will any IT companies recruit me ? or this gap in Job will become a problem ?

Comment: There is no crystal ball. We cannot tell you what you want to know. We cannot even guess, since obviously a gap of 2 months is nothing, while a gap of 20 years is a lot. You might get some educated guesses if you provided the size of the gap. But even then... we cannot possibly know.

Comment: I have been in this new business from past 6 months.

Comment: That subject line really needs to be changed to summarize the question better. Not up to editing it myself right now.

Answer (score 2):

Businesses fail. New businesses fail very often. Nobody will blame you for having taken six months to make the attempt.  Especially if you can explain what you learned from the experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your question. How is there a gap in employment history?

If for example you started last year, you'd say from January 1 to current I am head of my own manufacturing plant. Don't say it failed but list relevant jobs/skills within that domain. At the interview, simply say the business ultimately went under but during which the following was learned/applied.

I think if you did that it would pretty much cover all of your concerns when or if you get back to the job market.